# styleWithCSS for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, wysiwyg, rte

I'm building a custom RTE that converts user input to a homebrewn markup, now idiot that I am I did this using an iframe with designMode = "On" and got it to work in firefox using styleWithCSS = false so that I could easily convert the `<b>` (yes... b :( ) into my markup which would then output the proper code instead of me having to read from `<span style="...` now my problem is, I cant seem to find something that looks or acts like styleWithCSS = false for IE, Chrome or Opera, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Its okay if its `<strong>` instead of `<b>` as long as its one tag for one "effect"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
            try {
                Editor.execCommand("styleWithCSS", 0, false);
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    Editor.execCommand("useCSS", 0, true);
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        Editor.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, false);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Before any other execCommands.
Tested on ff3 ie7 ie8 safari chrome

Comment: I'll give it a go later today... yeah, I dont stop by that often, sorry.

Comment: Your welcome, if this my post was your answer, please mark it and let others know that.

Comment: why do you try the styleWithCSS twice, once with 0 and once with false?  Won't 0 cast to false?

Comment: Editor.execCommand("styleWithCSS", false, false) will not work on some old browsers. I do not remember exactly witch one :)

Comment: This doesn't work at all on IE11 or Edge :/ any solution guys?